# Android Emulator not Working on OSX

Tags: macos, android-studio, nativescript, android-virtual-device

I am trying to test my NativeScript Application on an Android emulator. So I followed the NativeScript instructions and installed the sdk and set up the emulator as instructed. But whenever I want to run an emulator (manually from Android Studio), nothing happens. I can see the "starting AVD" message on the bottom of Android Studio but there is no emulator popping out and no error displayed. Can someone tell me what might be wrong or where I can "debug" to see if he throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

I had installed android-sdk using brew as well as Android Studio. Somehow, having 2 installations was causing this problem. When I uninstalled my brew installation of the sdk using:

brew cask uninstall android-sdk

it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Genymotion virtual machines for android, it is much faster and provides different API versions etc.